# Download JSON async crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, crash

I download my Firebase database in json with AFNetworking 3. Everything works fine but there is a crash in the function cellForRoAtIndexPath.
Thanks

Work :

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"https://jojol-concours-lists.firebaseio.com/.json" parameters:URLParameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        self.contestArray = responseObject;

        [_collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Work :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.contestArray count];
}
```

Not work : (NSDictionary *array = [self.contestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];)

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                      cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        DemoCollectionViewCell *retVal = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCell"
                                                                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];

//////// Not work ///////
        NSDictionary *array = [self.contestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//////// Not work ///////

        retVal.name.text = @"";

        retVal.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        retVal.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        return retVal;
    }
```

JSON :

```
{
  "Concours-1" : {
    "Description" : "Description du concours",
    "Title" : "Titre"
  },
  "Concours-2" : {
    "Description" : "Description du concours",
    "Titre" : "iPhone 6"
  }
}
```

Log Crash :

-[**NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000086c8c0
2017-07-18 10:00:26.787 jojol67[7003:4420828] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000086c8c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c084b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e5c9141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0f4134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c00b840 ___forwarding_** + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c00b3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   jojol67                             0x000000010756db3f -[DEMOConcoursTableViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 191
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d162925 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 446
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d162761 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d1679bd -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4764
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d16d38e -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c8f355b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c6a4904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c698526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c6983a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c627e92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c654130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c654b37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c02a717 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c02a687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c00f720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c00f016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001103c2a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010c830134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  jojol67                             0x000000010752ef5f main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f31d65d start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

/////// Firebase realtime database ////////

[image]

Comment: A crash => You have a crash log then?

Comment: The error message is explicit and confirmed with the JSON structure: your JSON is a NSDictionary at top level, not an Array.

Comment: your self.contestArray is NSDictionary not NSArray so you must access with NSDictionary *array = [self.contestArray objectForKey:"key"]; use NSLog(@"%@",self.contestArray) to see the keys and values of self.contestArray

Comment: @ReinierMelian //////// work ////////
    NSDictionary *array = [self.contestArray valueForKey:@"Concours-1"];
    
    /////// not work (I need that one) ////////
    NSDictionary *array2 = [self.contestArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Indeed your retrieved dictionary don't have any array inside

Comment: You are using Firebase, did you set yourself the data? If YES, you may want to change your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help you for such responce:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict =responseObject;

NSArray *allKeys = [jsonDict allKeys];
NSMutableArray *allDataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int x = 0; x<allKeys.count; x++) {
    NSString *key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:x];
    [allDataArray addObject:[jsonDict valueForKey:key]];

    // then reload your collection on allDataArray
}
```

Comment: @victorbill Try this it will surly solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `id responseObject` is not an array because your JSON contains an object not an array. App crashes because you are calling `objectAtIndex` on a NSDictionary object.

If you want to access this JSON as an array, you may want to format it to something like this,

```
[{
    "Concours": 1,
    "Description": "Description du concours",
    "Title": "Titre"
}, {
    "Concours": 2,
    "Description": "Description du concours",
    "Titre": "iPhone 6"
}]
```

Comment: So how do we do that? Thanks

Comment: @victorbill I've added more info.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx  "Concours-1" and "Concours-2" are separated Object , not for the internal objects value... these are the main object

Comment: @victorbill check my answer it will help you 100% without any change in responce json. happy coding :)

Comment: @ParvendraSingh I could've provided the same solution, but it's an extremely bad practice and a design, which will lead to more difficulties in future. Since he's using a data source for a collection view right way to do is changing the JSON schema to an array format while it's still possible, rather than ending up with more critical problems later. Dictionaries are not ordered data structures , so that is another pitfall he has to deal with already with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Current JSON:

```
{
  "Concours-1" : {
    "Description" : "Description du concours",
    "Title" : "Titre"
  },
  "Concours-2" : {
    "Description" : "Description du concours",
    "Titre" : "iPhone 6"
  }
}
```

How it should be:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "Description du concours",
    "Title": "Titre"
  },
  {
    "Description": "Description du concours",
    "Titre": "iPhone 6"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**"-[NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000086c8c0 "**
It seems that the **self.contestArray** is **NSDictionary class**;

You can log the **responseObject** it maybe a Dictionary , not Array;